# rviz: get interactive object behind transparent object

Tags: ros, rviz, rviz-plugins, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am playing around with an rviz tool plugin and I'm trying figure out how to select an interactive marker that is behind a transparent non-interactive object.

Is there a way to parse the results from rviz::SelectionManager::pick to get handles to the objects further back in depth?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52853/rviz:-get-interactive-object-behind-transparent-object/) by [Kyle Strabala](https://answers.ros.org/users/1173/kyle-strabala/) on ROS Answers with karma: 186 on 2013-01-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The picking mechanism in RViz renders the scene to a separate buffer with a special "pick" scheme, and that will always only return one object id.

There is no nice general solution to this, but depending on what you want to do, you might want to use Ogre's scene query mechanism, or change the picking scheme (named "Pick") of the transparent object so that it is invisible in the picking buffer.

To debug this, RViz has a useful command line option "-v", which will make it publish the picking buffer to /rviz_debug/pick. You can then use the "select" tool to trigger the generation of a picking buffer (see screenshot).

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexKolb](https://answers.ros.org/users/20130/alexkolb/) on 2014-11-20**:
Hey i have the same problem right now but i just cant figure out how to access the picking scheme. Could you give me a hint how to do it. Do i have to create a object from SelectionManager or something like that? (sorry im new to C++)